# Python algorithm to find total of some numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

> By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent numbers on the row below, find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle below.
>
> ```
> 75
> 95 64
> 17 47 82
> 18 35 87 10    
> 20 04 82 47 65
> 19 01 23 75 03 34
> 88 02 77 73 07 63 67
> 99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
> 41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
> 41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
> 53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
> 70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
> 91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
> 63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
> 04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23
> ```

This is [Project Euler, Problem 18](http://projecteuler.net/problem=18).

I got an answer as 1064. But they say it is wrong. Help me...in python 2.7

This is my code:

```
s='''Here the sequence'''
s=s.split("\n")
value=0
total=0
for x in range(len(s)):
    y=s[x].split()
    if (value+1)>x:
        total+=int(y[value])
        print int(y[value])
    else:
        if int(y[value])>int(y[value+1]):
            total+=int(y[value])
            print int(y[value])
        else: 
            total+=int(y[value+1])
            print int(y[value+1])
            value+=1
print "Total:::%d"%total
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your algorithm is that you only explore a single path through the triangle: At each "junction", you always select the higher value and proceed down that path. But this ["greedy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) algorithm does not always work. Consider this example:

```
    1          Yours:    (1)           Best:   (1)
  1   2                 1  (2)               (1)  2
9   1   1             9  (1)  1            (9)  1   1
```

When presented with the choice of `1` or `2`, you select `2` and go down the right path, missing out the `9`. Instead, you have to consider *all* the paths. You can do this in a ["dynamic programming"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) kind of fashion, where you store the highest-possible value that can be reached in each cell and then just add them up. You can do this top-down or bottom-up, and then just select the highest value in the final row.

Example (bottom-up): In each step, add the maximum of the two adjacent lower cells to the cell above.

```
   5               5               5             5            5   ==> 5+17 
  2 4            2   4           2   4   ==> 2+11 4+13  ==> 13 17
 3 5 7   ==>  3+5 5+6 7+6  ==> 8  11  13
1 5 6 2
```

Implementing this idea in an algorithm is left as an excercise to the reader. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a greedy algorithm, which appends the largest adjacent number at every iteration. It produces a suboptimal solution. Simple explanation - consider just a triangle that consists of three top rows. Your solution will be 75 + 95 + 47 = 217. While the optimal solution in this case is 75 + 64 + 82 = 221. How to solve this? I would recommend designing a dynamic programming algorithm.